# iOS: tracking how users arrive at the app store page

Tags: ios

Is there a way to track what channels organic install users take to get to the app store page?

For example, Google Analytics show that organic users came from: google search / facebook app page / etc. But I am unable to find this information for iOS. The reason I ask this is to break down the percentage of organic users by how they found about my app.

For example, if my app had something like invitation features to Facebook friends, I will be able to pull the logs of the invitations sent. But I am unable to track how many people click the invitation and arrive at the app page to download the app.

Any tool or service that has this function?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The application it self can't know how the appStore was opened, the only way i know, is to build a web page that redirect users to the store, so you can set the link in the Facebook message for invitations and you can track the number of redirections.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yea, I was trying to find out where the organic users come from (facebook, website link, google search, etc). But it seems like it is impossible to do so unless it is tracked by the URL. You got me the type of answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a campaign-link to get the statistics into your iTunes connect!

> Campaigns are custom App Store links you can use in your marketing
>   material, websites, or advertising. Campaign links allow you to see
>   your app sales, usage, and monetization for specific campaigns.

https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/App%20Analytics_Campaigns